# textarea should resize it

Tags: html, css, textarea

When using a resizable `<textarea>` :

```css
#a { resize: horizontal; height: 200px; }
```

```html
<textarea id="a">Test</textarea>
```

**How to make it resizable from 0% to 100% browser-width?** (it seems impossible, even if we use min-width...)

Also all the vertical boundary between textarea and the rest of the page should display a resize cursor, why is it not displayed, even if using `resize: horizontal;`?

Comment: In what circumstances would you need it to be 0% width? Also, you are asking about a resizable textarea, but your example uses a fixed width one.

Comment: @FluffyKitten for example when you have two columns: one editor column on left, and one preview column on right. When you want to see preview only, you want to be able to drag the editor textarea column to 0 width.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I think it's not a fixed one, you can drag it from bottom right.

Comment: You mean that its resizable within the *browser*? Your question is tagged ***CSS*** so the assumption is that you meant with resizable with CSS. That behaviour is down to the browser's implementation (it behaves exactly the same way for me if I remove the `resize:horizontal` altogether). But logically it doesn't make sense to have  0% width (or very small width) textarea - it's purpose is for entering text, and making it very small would result in the text being vertical which is impractical.

Comment: @FluffyKitten what would be "resizable with CSS"? Is there another property in CSS than the one I used, that allows the user to click and drag to resize the textarea's width?

Answer (score 2):

Tada . Thanks @Basj.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  min-width: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: You can get exactly the same with no JS, no jQuery, but just setting `textarea { width: 0; }` in the CSS.